# Installing Windows On SDXC (not like source of ISO)

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, sd-card

I'm a  newbie on Macs and OS X.  I'm currently using "El Capitan" version 10.11.6

I have the Windows 10 Enterprise 64bits installer ISO.  I have doubts about Installing Windows on SDXC Card using Boot Camp.

**Is it Possible to do this and if so, is there a step-by-step or HOWTO available?**

**EDIT 1**

My Hard Disk is 128GB, I really need another partitions for *CentOS* and *Windows 10* then Is very few space for three OS.

And now I know the speed is very slow for SDXC (I was thinking in Transcend).

If I found a Speedest Hard Disk the USB speed will be a limitation.
Some clue to solve this limitation Space and Speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this?

With Windows?  No.  Technically, it's *possible* to boot an OS (like Linux for FreeBSD) off a SD card - you simply point your bootloader to the bootable partition of the SDXC card and away you go  But...

**Why would you want to do this?  It would be horribly slow.** 
(and by slow, I mean slow as molasses in winter slow)

Microsoft doesn't like people booting from **removable** drives and since the SD card reader is off your USB bus, it shows up as a removable device.  Linux doesn't have this limitation, however.

This doesn't, however, prevent you from putting a virtual HDD on the SD card and booting Windows in a virtualized environment like Parallels or VirtualBox.

#### Why you don't want to do this

Your SATA drive on your Mac transfers at 6Gb/s.  A USB 3.0 drive goes 5Gb/s.  Your SD card (assuming class 10) will go at most .5Gb/s (yes, only ***half a gigabit per second***).

***Basically,  you will be trying to install Windows on a disk that's 12x slower than the drive built in to your Mac**. *And that's at the highest speed possible that an SD card can go.*

I give more detail in an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240230/119271)

By trying to boot off the SDXC card, you would bring your MBP down to a crawl; to the point it would be torturous to us.  The best thing to do is to keep that SDXC card for pictures, or whatever file storage you need.

Comment: You data speeds are off. SATA is 6Gb/s, meaning gigabits, NOT gigabytes. This means it can go up to around 600 megabytes/second. USB 3.0 goes 5Gb/s, meaning 5 gigabits, and a theoretical speed of 640 megabytes/second. A quick lookup shows that the top speed of a SDXC/SDHC card is up to 312 megabytes/second.

Comment: @IronCraftMan  don't know why I typed bytes when I really meants bits.  I fixed it....  Thanks for the catch