# External Storage to LaptopStorage NAtive

Tags: macos, mac, usb

I have a 128gb sandisk USB for my macbook pro 2015 13' (the storage capacity for the laptop is 128gb). Can I make the USB like my SSD for my mac (on laptop) so combined it will be 256gb total?

Answer (score 4):

You could try making a DIY fusion drive, but I would expect [bad results due to the slowness of the USB drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240223/how-should-i-format-a-micro-sd-card-for-dropbox-storage).

- [Can I make a DIY Fusion Drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69538/can-i-make-a-diy-fusion-drive)

Worse - if you ever unplugged your USB drive or jolted it - the OS would likely crash. It would probably be better to just save less used files on the drive and mount it when needed.